# Facebook has detected App isn't using a secure connection followed by domain URL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app was working just fine and I could easily log in with facebook, but today, facebook login suddenly gave me this error message:
"Facebook has detected Superhero Maker isn't using a secure connection to transfer information. Until Superhero Maker updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log into it". After I closed the error message, I got this error message as well: "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."
I did not make any changes to my code, so I'm not sure what's going on. Also, the `FACEBOOK_ID` and `FACEBOOK_SECRET` match the app ID and app Secret from Facebook.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebookAuth'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
end
```

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
end
```

.env

```
FACEBOOK_ID=[facebook_id_here]
FACEBOOK_SECRET=[facebook_secret_here]
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def facebookAuth
    
    access_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.from_omniauth(access_token)  
    @user.facebook_token = access_token.credentials.token  
    refresh_token = access_token.credentials.refresh_token
    @user.facebook_refresh_token = refresh_token if refresh_token.present?
   
    if @user.save
        log_in(@user)
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
        redirect_to login_path
    end
  end   
end
```

Facebook Login Setting
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuWZU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
You should disable `HTTP Enforce` and Valid OAuth uri must be http:// not https://

Option 2:
You can create a local ssl certificate and run with `rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=localhost.key&cert=localhost.crt'`

Answer (score 0):

Check these steps to login facebook without Devise gem, for `Rails 6.1.3.2`!

`Step 1:` Create ssl connection by add `thin` gem

```
gem 'thin'

$ bundle install
```

Edit `config/application.rb` and add:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Run Terminal and type:

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 > host.key
$ chmod 400 host.key
$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key host.key -out host.cert
```

After these commands will create two file: `host.key` and `host.cert`. Copy them to ssl folder of your project location then run:

```
$ thin start --ssl --ssl-key-file=./ssl/host.key --ssl-cert-file=./ssl/host.cert
```

It will run project in default address: https://0.0.0.0:3000. If you want to run on https://localhost:3000, just type:

```
$ thin start -a localhost --ssl --ssl-key-file=./ssl/host.key --ssl-cert-file=./ssl/host.cert
```

`Step 2:` Add Jquery for Javascript library, run command:

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

Then, set content of `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
 })
)
module.exports = environment
```

`Step 3:` Add related gems and contents to omniauth

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection'
$ bundle install
```

Set `.env` at root folder:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=166...30
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=165a14...77e1d
```

Set init content for `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']
end
```

Edit `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebookAuth'
  root to: "pages#home"
end
```

Create `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`, it's main controller for facebook login processing:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def facebookAuth
    access_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    # @user = User.from_omniauth(access_token)  
    # @user.facebook_token = access_token.credentials.token  
    # refresh_token = access_token.credentials.refresh_token
    # @user.facebook_refresh_token = refresh_token if refresh_token.present?
    # if @user.save
    #     log_in(@user)
    #     redirect_to user_path(@user)
    # else
    #     redirect_to login_path
    # end
    Rails.logger.debug "Get name:"
    Rails.logger.debug access_token["info"]["name"]
    render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Loaded facebook finished!', name: access_token["info"]["name"] }, status: :ok
  end   

end
```

Add to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("jquery")

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '166...30',
    version: 'v4.0',
    cookie: true // IMPORTANT must enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  });
  console.log("fb init");
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And create simple controller `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

Add this file `app/views/pages/home.html.erb` to finish this question task:

```
Welcome to project railstrace !

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<p id="connect">
  <a href="#">Connect to FB!</a>
</p>

<p id="results" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.authResponse) {
        $('#connect').html('Connected! Hitting OmniAuth callback (GET /auth/facebook/callback)...');

        // since we have cookies enabled, this request will allow omniauth to parse
        // out the auth code from the signed request in the fbsr_XXX cookie
        $.getJSON('/auth/facebook/callback', function(json) {
          $('#connect').html('Connected! Callback complete.');
          $('#results').html(JSON.stringify(json));
        });
      }
    }); // if you want custom scopes, pass them as an extra, final argument to FB.login
  });
</script>
```

If you have any problems don't hesitate to tell me! Thank you!

Comment: If you can not run this project, you can assign direct ENV variables, or use gem 'figaro'!